# How do I de-MultiIndex a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I tried to merge two dfs (shown below) using the following:

[image: df1 and df2]

new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='barcode', how='left')

My expectation is that a new_df should be generated in which the cluster info from df2 is appended to df1. However, I get the following error message:

ValueError: The column label 'barcode' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.

Incidentally, I can merge df1 with df1 (not that this is of any use) but cannot merge df2 to df2 in the same manner. On closer inspection of df2, it is in multiIndex format (below), which I assume may be important.

MultiIndex([('barcode',),
('cluster',)],
)

Comment: Please provide reproducible objects for your two input dataframes, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have not provided the data so I can't guarantee that it will work. Though, I would expect a `.reset_index()` will allow you to remove the multi indexing of `df2`. You will then be able to merge your two dataframes.